# Professors Salary vs Alumni Earning: is the relation causal?

Tags: regression, wages, causality

Elyase İskender posted in his [blog](http://sayiyon.com/?p=1463) an interesting plot correlating Professors Salary and Alumni Earnings Relation in US Universities. Is there a good way to establish causality here?

Did the highest paid alumni receive a better education from the highest/best profs leading to higher wages? Or, is this a question of selection: the best/highest paid alumni self-selected into places offering the highest prof salaries and the best prospects?

[image]

Comment: I propose a random upward shock to the salaries of certain professors (myself in particular).   If the wages of my students in the future are higher than normal, we will have a good argument towards causality in this direction.